# Parallelization of file and network I/O operations

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, data-synchronization

### The Questions:

- Main Question: What's the best strategy to parallel these jobs?
- Ideas: How to speed up the process using other mechanisms like a second checksum (Adler32?)

## The Szenario:

I'm writing kind of a synchronization tool in java. Basically it downloads a repository from a webserver which represents the file/directory structure on the local machine and defines sources for the needed files in compressed form combined with hash values to verify files. A basic thing i guess.

### Requirements:

- Multi-platform java desktop application
- Best possible speed and parallelization

## Example structure: (best described using mods of a game)

### Example Repository File

```
{"name":"subset1", "mods":[
    {
        "modfolder":"mod1",
        "modfiles":[
            {
                "url":"http://www.example.com/file2.7z",
                "localpath":"mod1/file2",
                "size":5,
                "sizecompressed":3,
                "checksum":"46aabad952db3e21e273ce"
            },
            {
                "url":"http://www.example.com/file1.7z",
                "localpath":"mod1/file1",
                "size":9,
                "sizecompressed":4,
                "checksum":"862f90bafda118c4d3c5ee6477"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "modfolder":"mod2",
        "modfiles":[
            {
                "url":"http://www.example.com/file3.7z",
                "localpath":"mod2/file3",
                "size":8,
                "sizecompressed":4,
                "checksum":"cb1e69de0f75a81bbeb465ee0cdd8232"
            },
            {
                "url":"http://www.example.com/file1.7z",
                "localpath":"mod2/file1",
                "size":9,
                "sizecompressed":4,
                "checksum":"862f90bafda118c4d3c5ee6477"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

### Client file structure, as it should be after sync

```
    mod1/
         file2
         file1
    mod2/
         file3
         file1

// mod1/file2 == mod2/file2
```

**A special thing about the repository:**
The Repository got from the server represents only subsets of a bigger repository, because the user only needs a subtree, which is changing (also overlapping).
Sometimes the Repository consists of mod1 and mod2, sometimes mod1 and mod3 and so on.

### Work to be done:

- Download Repository and parse it (Net I/O)
- Mark files not in the repository for deletion at the end of the process (files may be copied because of same checksum) (File I/O)
- If file exists: Check checksum of existing file (checksum cache) (File I/O)
- If file not exists: Check checksumcache for identical files in other subtrees to copy the file instead of downloading it (Light file I/O)
- Download single file in compressed form (Net I/O)
- Extract compressed file (File I/O)
- Checksum of uncompressed file (File I/O)
- Cache checksum associated with file. (Light file I/O)

## My solution: (many different producers/consumers)

- The Checksum cache is using MapDBs persistent maps.
- ATM only md5 checksum is used.
- Queues: Every Workertype has a blocking queue (producer/consumer)
- Thread Pools: Every Workertype has a fixed Threadpool e.g. 3 Downloader, 2 Checksum, ...
- Workers distribute the current job to other queues: Downloader -> Extract -> Checksum

### Workertypes:

- Localfile Worker: Checks local file structure (using checksum cache),
  redirects work to Download-Worker, Delete-Worker
- Copy: Copies a file with same checksum to destination
- Download: Downloads a file
- Checksum: Checksum a file and inserts in checksumcache
- Delete: Delete a file
- Extract: Extracts a compressed file

Comment: "which represents the file/directory structure on the local machine" <-- I fail to understand that part?

Comment: I hope the extra json file made the szenario more clear

Comment: Yup... Could write a JSON Schema for such a file. So, basically, you have that JSON, the client walks it, downloads, extracts?

Comment: Yep, thats the job. Download, Extract, Checksum, Copy... as in the last paragraph. BTW thx i will check if a json schema is needed, for now the json is always valid and server trusted :)

Comment: I can write it for you, heck, I have even an implementation available and I am the author of the current core and validation specs :p

Comment: well, thx that sounds great :) i'm using gson, so not sure how to validate this schema, but if u have further info on this topic, i would appreciate an email

Comment: See my profile, my mail is in there

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/fge/5813367) is the schema for your file. Note that my implementation uses Jackson, but it is only a matter of converting from `JsonElement` to `JsonNode` (or the reverse), and a processor can be written for that.

Comment: See my edit. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best strategy to parallel these jobs?

You have I/O. And, probably, if one job is already in progress on one directory, another job cannot be run on the same directory at the same time.

So, you need locking here. Recommendation: use a locking directory on the filesystem, and use *directories*, not files, to lock. Why? Because directory creation is atomic (first reason), and because Java 6 does not support atomic file creation (second reason). In fact, you may even need two locking directories: one for content download, another for content processing.

The separation of download vs processing you have already done, so I have nothing more to say here ;)

I am not sure why you want to cache checksums however? It doesn't look that useful to me...

Also, I don't know how big the files you have to deal with are, but why bother with checking the existing directory contents etc vs extract the new directory and rename? Ie:

- extract new directory in `newdir`;
- checksums;
- move `dstdir` to `dstdir.old`;
- move `newdir` to `dstdir`;
- scrap `dstdir.old`.

This even means you could parallelize scrapping, but that is too much I/O parallelization... You'll have to limit the number of threads doing actual I/O.

**EDIT** Here is how I would separate processing:

- first of all, no checksums anymore on the archive itself, but there is a file in the archive which contains the MD5 sums of each file (for instance, `MD5SUMS`);
- two blocking queues: download -> replace, replace -> scrapping;
- one processor takes care of downloading; when it is done, it fills the download -> replace queue;
- another processor picks a task from the download -> replace queue; this task performs, in order, unarchive and checksumming; if both are correct, as mentioned above, it renames the existing directory, renames the extracted directory to the expected directory, and puts a scrapping task on the replace -> scrappint queue;
- the third, and last, processor, picks a task from the scrapping queue and performs deletion of the previous archive.

Note that the checksumming, if it is that heavy, could be parallelized.

Comment: first to locking: IMO it is possible to fully parallelize the file I/O. In my first approach a 'Job' is created for every 'File' of the repository. This file has only one state (is only in one queue at a time) e.g Job is currently downloading, 'checksumming'...
Second checksums: Files are 5MB in average but the whole directory to sync is 2GB in average. It's hard to checksum all files at the beginning. Second reason: It's possible that the file is identical to one file outside the current subset of the repository (downloaded time ago), so there's no way to identify the dup

Comment: OK, so the size may be a concern... As to locking, I merely suggested an exclusive locking mechanism; directory locking works great and is reliable, which is why I was suggesting it ;) By the way, is this Java 6 or 7? If 7 you should seriously consider switchin to `Paths` and `Files`

Comment: Can you please describe a case where locking of directories would be necessary? atm i can't see that case. Backward compatibility to java6 would be great, but if there's a great improvement in speed java7 is possible. Is there any?
EDIT: Maybe i found the confusion: Only one file in one 7z, directories are not included and created if needed

Comment: Not really, it is just that Java 7 can do `open(O_EXCL)` while Java 6 cannot. And directory locking always works. The scenario I had in mind was that if I/O bounded threads would try and pick whatever tasks are available concurrently: in this case a locking mechanism would be needed so that not two directories are treated at the same time. But if you use a blocking queue for I/O then such a mechanism is not necessary. It is just that the global throughput would probably be better, but this may be premature optimization.

Comment: However I still maintain that the directory scrapping solution is better: you only have to perform checksums _once_, on the downloaded directory. Calculating checksums is expensive!

Comment: Thx for your Edit, but i think there's a huge misunderstanding here. Each compressed file only consists of one file (no directory). Because the path is in the Repository, the file is extracted to that location ("localpath"). There's also no need for renaming directories. If a localfile is not existing, the file is downloaded, extracted to the localpath, done. If a localfile is existing, it is checked against the repository (checksum), if correct, keep the file, if not download, extract, checksum...

Comment: Aah, OK. This, in fact, was the misunderstanding: "Each compressed file only consists of one file (no directory)". I thought indeed that an archive was a whole directory in itself. So, the checksum in there matches the checksum of the uncompressed file? Also, why don't you send the whole directory at once in the archive?

Comment: The main reason is to speed up the server and client process. The second is obvious: If 1 out of 100 files changes (5KB / 3 GB), you have to download the whole package...

Comment: So, it means the checksum is _also_ calculated on the server side, correct? If so, why not, as a "pre download" protocol, exchange checksums so as to see whether the client should initiate a download to begin with?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32038/discussion-between-blang-and-fge)